# Hybrid property expression concatenation for both MySQL and SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, hybrid

`flask-sqlalchemy` model:

```py
from sqlalchemy import extract
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from app import db

class Entry(db.Model):
   date_order = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
   version_number = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False, default=1)

   @hybrid_property
   def display_name(self):
       return f"{self.date_order.year} ({self.version_number})"

   @display_name.expression
   def display_name(cls):
       return func.concat(extract("year", cls.date_order), " (", cls.version_number, ")")
```

This works with MySQL. I had to use `func.concat` because with the simple addition it would cast the date year to an integer and just add them together instead of concatenation. I tested with my custom API and Flask shell:

```py
In [1]: dp = Entry.query.first().display_name
In [2]: Entry.query.filter_by(display_name=dp).all()
Out[2]: [...returns a bunch of entries with that display name...]
```

But my testing environment runs an SQLite instance. I have this unit test:

```py
# `create_entry` fixture commits the instance to db

def test_user_display_name_expression(create_entry):
    entry = create_entry(date_order=date(2022, 11, 11), version_number=3)

    filtered = Entry.query.filter_by(display_name="2022 (3)").one()

    assert filtered == entry
```

This returns an error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: concat

Is there any way to create this concatenation expression so both SQL implementation would query on it?

Comment: You are not a newbie here, so please revise your question according SO guidelines, as well as common sense.

Comment: Yes, I am not a newbie, so I know there is always someone here who talks about common sense, etc. but gives zero insight what's their problem. If you need more information, please tell which part it is, otherwise I can't improve on my question. Remember, we have different perspectives and maybe something is obvious to you/me which is not for the other.

Comment: You need to provide a failing snippet and associated error information. *"I think the concatenation with a non-string value is the problem*" does not sound like you did sufficient debugging before posting a question. If you think so, then why haven't you tested it!?

Comment: @PChemGuy Thanks for the time taken for my question anyway. I have updated the question with more information on how I deduced that the concatenations is suspicious. Since the query runs - returns with no records - the error message does not provide any insight. If I query for the entry in the test, it exists. So it is not a different session instance issue imho.

Comment: Python versions?

Comment: In the failing test, replace the filtered query with non-filtered and print the result.

Comment: Python version is `3.10.4`. Tried debugging by printing the `entry = Entry.query.first()` and the query returns that single entry created in the previous line. It has all the correct properties we'd expect from. So the instance is surely existing. The `display_name` hybrid property  has the exact same value I am filtering for. Even an assertion between them (`assert entry.display_name == "2022 (3)"`) passes.

Comment: What if you replace the expression in the display_name property with expected literal?

Comment: Yes, if I write `return "2022 (3)"` for the expression it passes. And I can concatenate the empty string to it since both of them a are strings. It may be some type issue with SQLite that it can interpret the expression it builds onto but adding a string to it returns some casting error that may be error-handled or parsed to `None` inside.

Comment: I suppose it is time, if you haven't done so already, to make a basic module with the code executed by the test. Verify that you still have the issue, and take a look at the generated SQL.

Comment: The problem was that the concatenation does not work this way propery. I need `sqlalcheym.sql.func.concat`. The only problem that it returns `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such function: concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many inputs from 
[PChemGuy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17472988/pchemguy) I managed to find the issue:

Neither `func.concat` or adding non-casted properties work as concatenation.

Instead we need `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast` to cast every property to `sqlalchemy.String`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import extract, String
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast

    @display_name.expression
    def display_name(cls):
        return (
            cast(extract("year", cls.date_order), String)
            + " ("
            + cast(cls.version_number, String)
            + ")"
        )
```

Both MysQL and SQLite can understand this.